# Submitting Python file in batch mode in Livy(without Hadoop installed)

Tags: python, apache-spark, livy

i have made a simple python file which want to submit in Livy.Livy is currently running in `local` mode.Also I have mentioned following property in livy.conf file.

```
Property name: livy.file.local-dir-whitelist, 
value "/usr/local/livy/scripts"
```

My file is kept in following path "/usr/local/livy/scripts"

```
import json, pprint, requests, textwrap
host = 'http://localhost:8998'
data = {'kind': 'spark'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(host + '/sessions', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
r.json()
```

I am submitting it using `curl` as follows:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/usr/local/livy/scripts/pi.py"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 10.140.178.24:8999/batches
```

It is giving me following error:

```
requirement failed: Local path /usr/local/livy/scripts/pi.py cannot be added to user sessions.
```

My Ubuntu system only have following things:

```
a)Spark
b)Livy
c)Java
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For people using incubating mode of livy for first time,kindly check that the template file is renamed with stripping off `.template` in `livy.conf.template`.Then make sure that the following configurations are present in it.

```
livy.spark.master = local
livy.file.local-dir-whitelist = /path/to/script/folder/
```

Kindly make sure that `forward slash` is present in end of path

Then write url in following manner for

**Python:**

```
curl -v -X POST --data '{"file": "/path/to/script/folder/name-of-python-file.py"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches
```

**Note**:It will not accept relative path,whole absolute path needs to be defined in it.

Answer (score -1):

curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/usr/local/livy/scripts/pi.py"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 10.140.178.24:8999/batches
**{"id":2,"state":"starting","log":[]}**

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? What was the problem and how your solution solves it?